# Throttle a Server Script with Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, throttling

I have a (python) script on my server which I don't want to be executed too often by the same person/bot. Every 5 seconds is ok, but if someone tries to run it more often, it would just harm my server...

Since the app is just a small weekend project I don't want to use some sophisticated fraud/ddos protection system. There is supposed to be a simple way to accomplish that with Nginx `ngx_http_limit_req_module`.

I find the manual kinda confusing... Do you have samples for this **scenario**?

**Every ip should only be allowed to connect to a certain location every 5 seconds.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The rate is specified in requests per second (r/s). If a rate of less than one request per second is desired, it is specified in request per minute (r/m). For example, half-request per second is 30r/m.

```
# Allow not more than 12 request per minute at an average, with bursts not exceeding 1 requests.
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=12r/m;

server {
    location /path/to/python/script.py {
        limit_req zone=one burst=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "...with bursts not exceeding 1 requests." mean in this context?

Comment: > Sets the shared memory zone and the maximum burst size of requests. If the requests rate exceeds the rate configured for a zone, their processing is delayed such that requests are processed at a defined rate. Excessive requests are delayed until their number exceeds the maximum burst size in which case the request is terminated with an error 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable). By default, the maximum burst size is equal to zero.

Comment: Official documentation is very well written so I would suggest you read the it: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/